# Why is including a .c file in another .c file an "unacceptable practice according to Indian Hill Standards?"

Tags: standards

According to my teacher including a .c file in another .c file (instead of creating a header for said file and compiling them together) is unacceptable

What are the risks of doing this or why is it considered unappropiate?

Comment: Included file can be compiled twice(double) causing link error

Comment: E.g. a.c and b.c has exactly  same function